# Import author list from a txt file in latex

Tags: titles, verbatim

I'm trying to import author list to my latex article. But keep getting errors.
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\title{\verbatiminput{title.txt}}
\author{\verbatiminput{authors.txt}}
\date{\verbatiminput{date.txt}}
\begin{document}
   \maketitle
   Hello world!
\end{document}
```

and the authors.txt

```
ya zhang
```

and I got this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.7    \maketitle

?
```

Can anyone help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\input` rather than `\verbatiminput`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,verbatim}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{filecontents,verbatim}
\begin{filecontents*}{authors.txt}
ya zhang
\end{filecontents*}
\title{My title}%\title{\input{title.txt}}
\author{\input{authors.txt}}
\date{\today}%\date{\input{date.txt}}
\begin{document}
   \maketitle
   Hello world!
\end{document}
```

If you wish to format the title with different fonts (the only gain from using something like `\verbatiminput`, without more detail provided), you can supply that as part of the arguments:

```
\title{\ttfamily My title}
%...
```

Comment: I'm wondering why the author element can't use verbatiminput? The title and date elements works well. Could you tell me?

Comment: @user2522104: The author is handled differently than the title and date. The latter two are set as-is, while the former is set inside a `tabular`, where some characters have special meaning. The only reason to use `\verbatiminput` would be if you require special symbols to be interpreted in the regular way (which should not be the case with authors).